# How to generate xml via SAXBuilder with namespace?

Tags: java, sax

xml as String:

```
String inputStr = "<f:table f:id=\"1\">\n" +
                "  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>\n" +
                "  <f:width>80</f:width>\n" +
                "  <f:length>120</f:length>\n" +
                "</f:table>";
```

I want to generate this xml to jdom document :

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(inputStr);
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = builder.build(stringReader);
```

But the `doc` is null, and when I want to get root element, I get a `NullPointerException`.

How I can generate xml from string with namespace?

Comment: I would think you would need the `<?xml...>` processing instruction and a `xmlns:f="...namespace..."` in your `<table>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be getting a `org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException` when you run that code. This is what I get:

> org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: The prefix "f" for element "f:table" is not bound.

So as I mentioned in comments, you need to provide a namespace URI for the `f` prefix, like this:

```
String inputStr = "<f:table f:id=\"1\" xmlns:f=\"http://millka_15.namespace\">\n" +
```

I've just used `http://millka_15.namespace` as a placeholder, I assume you know what the actual namespace URI should be.

The following code:

```
String inputStr = "<f:table f:id=\"1\" xmlns:f=\"http://millka_15.namespace\">\n" +
        "  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>\n" +
        "  <f:width>80</f:width>\n" +
        "  <f:length>120</f:length>\n" +
        "</f:table>";

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(inputStr);
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = builder.build(stringReader);

System.out.println(doc);
```

Results in this output:

```
[Document:  No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is [Element: <f:table [Namespace: http://millka_15.namespace]/>]]
```

Comment: Hi, your solution works for version of jdom start from b8, but I use b7 version and I don't have ways to change revision. In version b7 attributes  don't have namespace.

Comment: @millka_15 I just tested with b7 and it works fine for me.

Comment: Do you have namespace for attributes?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. If your question is now about something else, please edit your question to reflect the problem you are actually having.